# How can I get the id of the aspusers table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity

I have created a login with `asp.net core` and `Identity`; I already know how to get the `username` and the `role`, but how do I get the `id` that is generated automatically when creating a user?

I have already managed to get the id but only if I put it as a constant in the `NameIdentifier` within the `Claim`, and I want to get it every time a user logs in, since constant will always give me the same user even if it has already changed.

This way I can get the id, only if I put it constant:

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "f75ce3f5-f51b-41af-bedb-cfefbe2327a1"),
```

here I create a list of claims:

```
 private UserToken BuildToken(UserInfo userInfo, IList<string> roles)
        {

                var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, userInfo.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfo.Email),                
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "f75ce3f5-f51b-41af-bedb-cfefbe2327a1"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        };
```

here I look for the user id in the controller:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
            concepto.id_Prop = Guid.Parse(user.Id.ToString());
            context.Add(concepto);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();            
            return concepto.id_Conceptos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try the below statement:

```
var userId  = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
```

Or:

```
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

By this way, in asp.net core 3.1, I can get the logged in user's id.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, if the id is obtained with that code, but also I had to change the parameters where I create the buildtoken so that in the claim I make it can pass the id